# How do I mix jq operators?

Tags: json, bash

I'm using jq to analyze JSON content via bash. Works well so far.

Now, I have this content:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55a3fb74e4b0feb11ba5bec2" }, 
"alertId" : 15, "headline" : "License for XXXXXX is about to expire", 
"includedItems" : []}
```

Now I use jq easily to get the alertId and headline, like so:

jq .alertId,.headline FILENAME

But, I also want to add a count of items in the includedItems array. Like so:

jq '.includedItems | length' FILENAME

This work, but I need it all part of one command. The reason is that FILENAME is a file with a huge amount of JSON and if I were to run the commands separately, I'd spend a lot of time trying to thread the outputs together. So instead, I was hoping to find a way to achieve something like this:

jq .alertId,.headline,'.includedItems | length' FILENAME

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `'.alertId,.headline,.includedItems | length'` is that `,` has higher precedence than `|`, so it's equivalent to `'(.alertId,.headline,.includedItems) | length'`. Since you want your `|` to have higher precedence — you want `.includedItems | length` to be just a single list-item — you need to group it with parentheses:

```
jq '.alertId, .headline, (.includedItems | length)' FILENAME
```